# Let $E_o$ denote the set of interior points of a set E. Then, $E_o$ is always open

Tags: general-topology, analysis

This problems is exercises #9-Ch.2 in PMA of Rudin

Let $E_o$ denote the set of interior points of a set $E$. 
Prove that $E_o$ is always open.

Could you prove this in a easy way please?
Or I want some hint to be helpful solving this.

Comment: Do you know what a topology on a set $X$ is? What does an open set means or what is the definition of the interior of a set?
If any of these answers is no, I reccomend you find the book Topology by James Munkres and read it's 2nd chapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point $x\in E$ is an interior point provided that there exists an open set $V_x\subset E$ where $x\in V_x$. Note that, by definition, any element of $V_x$ is an interior point of $E$, i.e. $V_x \subset E_o$ for all $x$. Then
$$E_o = \bigcup_{x\in E} \{x\} \subset \bigcup_{x\in E} V_x \subset E_o$$
Since the first and last expressions are equal, 
$$E_o = \bigcup_{x\in E} \{x\} =\bigcup_{x\in E} V_x =E_o$$
And so $E_o$ is a union of open sets, and therefore open.

(unless you define an interior point as an element of the interior of the set, where the interior of $E$ is defined as the union of all open subsets of $E$; in which case, $E_o$ is already defined as a union of open sets)